# Как в запросе вернуть значения столбца с заменой их по условию?

Tags: sql, postgresql

К примеру, имеется следующая таблица:

```
a  b    
A1|10|
A2|11|
A3|14|
A4| 3|
A5| 8|
A6|12|
```

Как написать запрос, который вернет все элементы столбца a, и те элементы столбца b, которые больше 10? При этом, вместо значений, которые меньше, либо равны 10, будет написано "неуд".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

что-то вроде такого:

```
select a, 
       case when b > 10 then to_char(b, '999999')
            else 'неуд'
       end as b
from table_name;
```

или еще проще (спасибо @Vitalts за [подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567143/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-postgresql/567158#comment745482_567158))

```
select a, 
       case when b > 10 then b::text
            else 'неуд'
       end as b
from table_name;
```

PS я этот код не тестировал...

Comment: Ошибка:  функция to_char(integer) не существует

Comment: какая у вас версия PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: попробуйте `to_char(b, '99')`...

Comment: Да, так работает. Спасибо! Какой максимальное значение можно поставить вместо 99? Числа, которые больше 99, выводятся как ###

Comment: поставтье столько девяток, чтобы "покрывало" максимальное число - например `9999` если нет чисел из более чем 4-х цифер

Comment: b::text и никаких to_char ;)

Comment: @Vitalts, спасибо! добавил в ответ...